# Laravel relationship throughout multiple tables

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, relationship

I have a "daisy chain" of tables. I managed to get three deep table query and i'm not sure how to go about further.

[image: My schema]

I got through vehicles->complement->deliveries, but i'm not sure how to proceed to get employees.
As you can see, they're all connected via foreign keys and docs don't explain more then three deep.

Here is how how i got so far, which works for three deep:

```
public function deliveries(){
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Delivery", "App\Complement", "vehicle_id", "delivery_id");
    }
```

It's classic, `belongsToMany` relationship that targets three deep. Not sure how to proceed to forth one...

**Edit1:**

Vehicles model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vehicle extends Model
{
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'registration', 'sec_id', "workOrganization_id"
    ];

    /*public function deliveries(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Delivery",'vehicle_id');
    }*/

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User", 'sec_id', "id");
    }

    public function type(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\VehiclePivot", 'vehicle_type_id', "id");
    }

    public function workOrganization(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\WorkOrganization", 'workOrganization_id', "id");
    }

    public function deliveries(){
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Delivery", "App\Complement", "vehicle_id", "delivery_id");
    }

}
```

Deliveries model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Delivery extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'deliveries';
    protected $fillable = [
        'load_place', 
        'unload_place',
        "comment",
        "time_in",
        "time_out",
        "operator_id",
        "sec_id"
    ];

    public function operator(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Employee",'operator_id');
    }

    public function enteredBy(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User",'sec_id');
    }

    public function complement(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Complement", 'delivery_id');
    }

}
```

Complement model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Complement extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'complement';
    protected $fillable = [
        'delivery_id', 
        'vehicle_id',
    ];

    public function vehicles(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Vehicle", 'vehicle_id');
    }

}
```

Employees model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'lastName', 
        'firstName', 
        "work_org_id",
        "sec_id",
        "avatar"
    ];

    public function work_organization(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\WorkOrganization",'work_org_id');
    }

    public function enteredBy(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User",'sec_id');
    }

    public function deliveries(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Delivery",'operator_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: could you please paste all 4 models code here.

Comment: @Dolar done. Not sure why you need them though, i explicitly said and it's shown in image how they're connected.

Comment: @Dolar I kind a figured it out also. Funny thing is, that i had same problem, but forgot about dot syntax.

Comment: could you please share your syntax

Comment: @Dolar shared..

Comment: The belongsToMany relationships probably don't work. The second parameter should be the table name (complement), not the model (Complement)

Comment: @IGP Rectified models. See my answer.

Comment: It looks good! I'm not sure if the date parts will work because of the Closure. I think it should be `when($date->start_date, function ($query) use ($date) {`

Comment: @IGP It works. I tested it on simple stuff first and just expanded on that.

Answer (score 1):

Dot syntax is solution here.
Simply "connect" models as you were connecting tables with foreign keys.
But in models, you'll use relationship methods.
Example:

Vehicle has "Complements" method which finds all complements, then in Complement model you got "Deliveries" method which find all deliveries connected with individual delivery, then you have yours "Employees" method which finds employees which handle individual delivery.

Model's methods either use "belongsTo" or "belongsToMany" relationships which depends how you defined your tables.

And here are models with their methods:

Vehicle model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vehicle extends Model
{
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'registration', 'sec_id', "workOrganization_id"
    ];

    public function complements(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Complement", 'vehicle_id', "id");
    }

}
```

Complement model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Complement extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'complement';
    protected $fillable = [
        'delivery_id', 
        'vehicle_id',
    ];

    public function deliveries(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Delivery", 'delivery_id', "id");
    }

}
```

Delivery model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Delivery extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'deliveries';
    protected $fillable = [
        'load_place', 
        'unload_place',
        "comment",
        "time_in",
        "time_out",
        "operator_id",
        "sec_id"
    ];

    public function employees(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Employee", 'operator_id', "id");
    }

}
```

And here is how i finally called them in controller:

```
if($request->vehicle_id && Vehicle::find($request->vehicle_id)){
                        
                        $vehicles = Vehicle::with("complements.deliveries.employees", ...$request->Vehicle)
                        ->when($dates->start_date, function ($query, $date) {
                            $query->where('updated_at', '>=', $date);
                        })
                        ->when($dates->end_date, function ($query, $date) {
                            $query->where('updated_at', '<=', $date);
                        })->find($request->vehicle_id);

                    }
                    else{

                        $vehicles = Vehicle::with("complements.deliveries.employees", ...$request->Vehicle)
                        ->when($dates->start_date, function ($query, $date) {
                            $query->where('updated_at', '>=', $date);
                        })
                        ->when($dates->end_date, function ($query, $date) {
                            $query->where('updated_at', '<=', $date);
                        })->get();

                    }
```

There are also some dates, but they aren't important, just to sift through needed data.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 3 "routes" to get from the Vehicle model to the Employee model

1. Vehicle hasMany Complement belongsTo Delivery belongsTo Employee.
2. Vehicle hasMany Complement belongsToMany Employee
3. Vehicle belongsToMany Delivery belongsTo Employee

In my opinion, route number 3 is the easiest.

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    public function deliveries()
    {
        // belongsToMany's 2nd parameter is the pivot table, not the pivot model. Rest of the parameters should be okay to omit in this case
        return $this->belongsToMany(Delivery::class, 'complement')
                    ->as('complement')
                    ->using(Complement::class)
                    ->withPivot(['sec_id'])
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

```php
class Delivery extends Model
{
    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'operator_id');
    }
}
```

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::with('deliveries.employee')->...->get();

foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {
    $vehicle->... // all vehicles columns
    foreach ($vehicle->deliveries as $delivery) {
        $delivery->... // all deliveries columns
        $delivery->complement->... // all complement columns (pivot table)
        $delivery->employee->... // all employees columns
    }
}
```

Comment: This is ok if i didn't prepared tables with foreign key's and models with relationships methods for simple daisy chain with dot syntax. PS: There are routes that handle individual stuff that you described. I choose to omit them, since they are not needed in this particular use case, sort of, best to have *them until achieve what i actually want to achieve.